# How can I prevent the Caspian Sea to be filled in as a land when using the map function (mapproj package) in R ?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
map(database="world", col="grey80", fill=TRUE)
```

With this code, the countries should be coloured in grey and the major water bodies should stay white. However, the Caspian Sea is coloured in grey as well. How can I prevent that?

Comment: some context would be helpful. What packages are you using? There is no `map` function in base R. What is the database?

Comment: [works for me](http://i.imgur.com/EczGpF6.png)

Comment: I am using the package "mapproj" in RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I finally managed to solve this problem:

```
map.1=map(database="world", col="grey80", fill=TRUE)
map.2=map(database="world", regions="Caspian Sea", col="white", fill=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```